# Database not shown in ListView, only the image

Tags: android, listview

This is the code that I use for my `Listview` which I got reference for some website. It shows a whole list of image. Which area do I have to place in my database to set the text for toptext and bottom text?

```
public class List_View extends ListActivity {

  private DBAdapter db; 

  private TextView toptext; 
  private TextView bottomtext;
  private ListView lv; 

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
   try{ 

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.list); 
    db = new DBAdapter(this); 

    toptext = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.toptext); 
    bottomtext = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.bottomtext); 

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    HashMap<String, String> item;
    for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++) {

            item = new HashMap<String, String>();
            item.put("Date:", "Saved Date" );
            item.put("Title:", "Saved Title" );
            list.add(item);
    }
```

The SimpleAdapter part:

```
    SimpleAdapter notes = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.view_list,
                            new String[] { "date", "title" }, 
                            new int[] {R.id.toptext, R.id.bottomtext });
    setListAdapter(notes);

   } catch(Throwable e){ 

            Log.e("DBAdapter",e.toString()); 
   } 
     }
```

and this is the database part:

```
    public Cursor getAllEntry() 
    {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_2, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID2,
                KEY_TITLE,
                KEY_ENTRY,
                KEY_MOOD,
                KEY_DATE,
                KEY_TIME},
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);
    }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear... it would help if you explain it better...

Comment: Oh ok. I followed this example from some particular website. And the listview that I want has an image on the left, and on the right is 2 textview. I have them stored in my database already. And now I cant show it out. Only the image cames out. The textview not out... 

SO yeah. I shall place my database part in.

Answer (score 1):

some modification in your code...and you get result

first declare Cursor, Adapter class in your ListActivity class

```
    private NCursorAdapter adapter = null;    
    private Cursor mNotesCursor;

    mNotesCursor = db.getAllEntry();
            startManagingCursor(mNotesCursor);
if (adapter == null) {
            adapter = new NCursorAdapter(this, mNotesCursor);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            adapter.changeCursor(mNotesCursor);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

you must create NCursorAdapter class in your application.

```
public class NCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private Cursor mCursor;
    private Context mContext;
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;


    public NCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));

        TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
        date.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date")));

    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.data, parent, false);

        return view;
    }

}
```

here data.xml file is your custom layout. which content two textview....
"title" and "date" your database table column  name...